Webflux Requests handled by MVC
I want to have MVC Servlet Based & Reactive Rest Api's together in a single Spring Boot App of version 3.2 using openJDK 17.
I created a dummy app and tested a webflux api call with 2 scenarios:

Using MVC+Webflux dependency

Using only Webflux dependency


Here are the logs for a webflux based rest api call:
MVC + Webflux dependency
 
        15:53:17.915 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/webflux", parameters={}
        15:53:17.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.example.demo.WebFluxApi#webfluxEndpoint()
        15:53:17.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager - Started async request
        15:53:17.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager - Async result set, dispatch to /webflux
        15:53:17.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting but response remains open for further handling
        15:53:17.917 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ASYNC" dispatch for GET "/webflux", parameters={}
        15:53:17.917 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Resume with async result ["Hello from Spring WebFlux"]
        15:53:17.918 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Using 'text/html', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
        15:53:17.918 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Writing ["Hello from Spring WebFlux"]
        15:53:17.918 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "ASYNC" dispatch, status 200


Only Webflux dependency   
    
        15:55:12.206 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [a00e8884-1] HTTP GET "/webflux"
        15:55:12.233 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - [a00e8884-1] Mapped to com.example.demo.WebFluxApi#webfluxEndpoint()
        15:55:12.249 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseBodyResultHandler - [a00e8884-1] Using 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] and supported [text/plain;charset=UTF-8, text/event-stream, text/plain;charset=UTF-8, */*]
        15:55:12.250 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseBodyResultHandler - [a00e8884-1] 0..1 [java.lang.String]
        15:55:12.254 [reactor-http-epoll-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.HttpLogging - [a00e8884-1] Writing "Hello from Spring WebFlux"

I expected the reactive infrastructure to handle webflux request in MVC+webflux config but according to the classes processing the request, it seems still MVC is handling it. Why?
@RestController
public class WebFluxApi {

    @GetMapping("/webflux")
    public Mono<String> webfluxEndpoint() {
        return Mono.just("Hello from Spring WebFlux");
    }
}

@RestController
public class RestControllerApi { 

    @GetMapping("/rest2")
    @ResponseBody
    public String mvcEndpoint() {
        return "Hello from Spring rest2";
    }
}

My second question is if I configure only Webflux, and call classic MVC Rest api "rest2", it is handled by Webflux. Can WebFlux really run it in MVC fashion, I mean blocking without breaking legacy MVC code?
